# Search database based on datagridview column?

Tags: vb.net

Database search based on a specific column of Datagrid View results in finding the first row in the search interval, and this row is not my goal ... Why does a row-by-row search find only the first row?

i am working with vb.net 2015 & sql server 2014

This is my attempt to write a search code
Please help me..

```
  Try
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(i)
            If DataGridView1.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
                If CBool(row.Cells("انتخاب").Value) = True Then

                    Dim rd As SqlDataReader
                    Dim con As New SqlConnection()
                    con.ConnectionString = (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString)
                    con.Open()
                    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT F_Takhsise_SatheTafzili_B_Moin.ID,F_Takhsise_SatheTafzili_B_Moin.Acckind,
                                                  F_Takhsise_SatheTafzili_B_Moin.StmoinName, 
                                                   F_Takhsise_SatheTafzili_B_Moin.UkolCode,
                                                    F_Takhsise_SatheTafzili_B_Moin.UmoinName,
                                                       F_Takhsise_SatheTafzili_B_Moin.Code_Sathe5,
                                                        F_Takhsise_SatheTafzili_B_Moin.Sathe5, 
                                                         F_Takhsise_SatheTafzili_B_Moin.Code_Sathe6,
                                                          F_Takhsise_SatheTafzili_B_Moin.Sathe6,
                                                         F_Takhsise_SatheTafzili_B_Moin.Id_F_AnvaeSanadeHesabdari,
                                                        F_Takhsise_SatheTafzili_B_Moin.name
                                                        from F_Takhsise_SatheTafzili_B_Moin
                                                       where F_Takhsise_SatheTafzili_B_Moin.name = '" & row.Cells(8).Value.ToString() & "'"
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    If rd.HasRows = True Then
                        Do
                            While rd.Read()
                                ID_code_Sathe5 = rd("code_Sathe5").ToString
                                ID_acckind = rd("acckind").ToString
                                ID_ukolcode = rd("ukolcode").ToString
                                ID_F_Takhsise_SatheTafzili_B_Moin = rd("id").ToString
                            End While
                        Loop While rd.NextResult
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Comment: If you run the same query directly on the database, do you get multiple rows? How do you know you you're only get the first row back, as it looks like your While loop is assigning the results to the same variables each time, overwriting previous values.

Comment: Thanks for your comment  
Andrew Mortimer

I apologize a lot for the correction I made in query.
Yes, I executed the query directly on the sql Server and got the answer. The result I get from this query ,I put it in the insert statement and save it in another table..

Comment: Andrew Mortimer
 Due to the direct execution of query in SQL Server, it finds only one row and ignores the other rows checked in Data Grid View. While in the search table and datagridview there are two rows based on this query shold  be find..